# Only Legacy routing is available after fresh install of NuGet package

Tags: nancy

For some reason after installing Nancy I only have access to what is referred to in [the documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes) as the legacy way to do routing :

```
Get["/"] = _ => "Hello World!";
```

The new syntax :

```
Get("/products/{id}", _ =>
    {
        //do something
    });
```

Results in the compiler error :

> Non-invocable member 'NancyModule.Get' cannot be used like a method.

I installed the NuGet package for Nancy 1.4.3 in a class library project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new syntax is in the 2.0 pre-release versions so you either need to check the "pre-release" checkbox in the Nuget UI, or use -pre if you are using the commandline.

Edit: the docs are a bit screwy there, not sure why they've been updated like that, but the "legacy routing" section is what you need if you want to use a non-prerelease version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought it was a stable version, I prefer to stick to the legacy syntax to use a stable version on that one.

Comment: The docs were a bit screwed,I've reverted the last change now, this is the url you need: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes - you're not using "legacy routing" thats for a much older version. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, no worries at all